# Выполнение скрипта который занимает много времени

Tags: php

Есть скрипт, который выполняется примерно 5-7 минут. Естественно пользователю ждать не хочется этого.

Вопрос. Каким образом сделать чтобы пользователь инициировал выполнения скрипта, но при этом мог даже закрыть браузер, а скрипт чтобы продолжил выполняться до конца?

Comment: 1) Сделать так чтобы скрипт был доступен внешне. 2) Вызвать `CURL` к этому адресу с ожиданием в `250мс` - этого хватит.

Comment: @Manitikyl то есть это что-то вроде крона?

Comment: Ближе к демону. Хоть крон и является демоном, но тут принципы работы, как видите, разные.

Comment: а что если постоянно работающий воркер?

Comment: @Manitikyl не совсем понял о чем вы...

Comment: Как вариант даже скорее всего подойдёт exec 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.exec.php

При повторных запросах проверять статус и ждать пока не закончит работу ваш долгий скрипт

Comment: @Денис скрипты, которые работают сами по себе, называются демонами. Есть демоны планировщики - типа крона. Есть обычные демоны в его классическом виде: `while(TRUE) {}`. Т.е. работающий постоянно. У вас-жеж получается что демон будет работать только тогда, когда надо (когда вы его вызовете).

Comment: Не писать хардкод

Comment: Если вебсерверу тебуется 5-7 мин для обработки запроса - 100% там что-то не так. Если не комерческая тайна- чем скрипт занимается? Может посоветуем как мохно упростить или что лучше использовать

Comment: Я тоже думаю что надо оптимизировать скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

1. либо реализовать очередь - Mysql таблица , дергать кроном.
2. либо копию скрипта запускать 
   passthru('(php -f '.PATH_DIR.'your_script.php & ) >> /dev/null 2>&1');
   но для этого конечно права должны быть у веб-юзера

Answer (score 0):

Если окружение позволяет (дешёвый хостинг точно нет), то можно [отключить остановку скрипта](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.ignore-user-abort.php) после отключения клиента:

```
ignore_user_abort(true);
```

Можно попробовать запустить отдельный дочерний процесс ([proc_open](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.proc-open.php) или [pcntl_fork](http://php.net/manual/ru/function.pcntl-fork.php)) и в нём выполнять долгоиграющие задачи. Но это тоже не сработает на хостинге и не сработает из-под апача (про nginx не знаю, поправьте если кто в курсе).

Проще всего конечно сохранить этот запрос как задание (в базе или в том же rabbitmq) и обработать его уже отложено по расписанию кроном.